# Indentation after display-style math

Tags: math-mode, indentation, displaystyle

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find this particular problem anywhere.

After a displayed math environment, there is a tiny indentation that I cannot seem to get rid of no matter what I try to do. For example, this code:

```
language, and defined in~\Cref{fig:semanticsEnv,fig:semantics}. The judgment
takes the form
\[
   Judgement
\]
where $\Sigma : TermVar -> Exp$ is an environment mapping term variables to
expressions and is what we use to allow us to deal with function
```

produces the following output:

[image]

Out of desperation, I have also tried adding a `\noindent` but with the exact same output.

The part that really confuses me is that it isn't even enough indentation for a paragraph, so it seems like something to do with the spacing/text-packing algorithm..

Any help would be very much appreciated.

## Edit 1:

I have managed to work around the problem, but I don't understand why it works...

I checked for and made sure there weren't any whitespace characters after the `\]` but the space still remained. However, once I put the 'where' on the same line as the end of the `\]`: `\]where..` the space disappeared. i.e., the following gets rid of the weird indentation:

```
language, and defined in~\Cref{fig:semanticsEnv,fig:semantics}. The judgment
takes the form
\[
   Judgement
\]where $\Sigma : TermVar -> Exp$ is an environment mapping term variables to
expressions and is what we use to allow us to deal with function
```

## Edit 2 (with a somewhat compilable example):

It appears as though this is an issue caused either by the particular (non-standard) class that I'm using, or by the interaction of that class with the `amsmath` package.

Here is a minimal compilable example (using `pdflatex`). Although you'll need the JFP class (along with possible supporting files all of which can be found
[here](https://github.com/bitemyapp/doc-prep/tree/master/ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/jfp-cls).)

It appears as though this only happens when the `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` line is present.

Here's the example:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{./styles/jfp1}

\title{Test}
\author[foo]
{FOO}

\begin{document}

\section{No Indentation Afterwards}
\lipsum[1]
\[
Math
\]where \lipsum[1]

\section{Indentation Afterwards}
\lipsum[1]
\[
Math
\]
where \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Delete the line break (all whitespaces, resp.) between `\]` and "where". A cleaner solution would be to use AmsMath the equation* environment.

Comment: I've checked for trailing whitespace, and made sure that there isn't any whitespace between the `\]` and "where" but sadly the space persists :(

Also just tried using the `equation*` environment as well, but sadly that doesn't change anything either

Comment: @TimZakian Please, post a complete compilable example.

Comment: This is clearly a space that kicks in, but the standard `\[...\]` doesn't produce it. The only possibility is that you (or the class/template you're using) modified the definition for `\]`.

Comment: @egreg That appears to be the case. I'm using a non-standard class, but once I tried it out in the `article` class it all seemed to work fine. I've added a minimal compilable example above in case anyone is interested.

Comment: @Tim I see no minimal example. Where can the class be found?

Comment: @egreg Should be up now, sorry about the delay.

Comment: @Tim And found the cause very easily. Look at the footnote to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `jfp1` class does

```
\@namedef{equation*}{$$}
\@namedef{endequation*}{$$}
```

which is quite incorrect.<sup>1</sup>

Loading `amsmath` with `\RequirePackage` is not the solution.

```
\documentclass{jfp1}

% fix the class's abominable definitions
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
%% end fix

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test}
\author[foo]{FOO}

\begin{document}

\section{No Indentation Afterwards}
\lipsum[1]
\[
Math
\]where \lipsum[1]

\section{Indentation Afterwards}
\lipsum[1]
\[
Math
\]
where \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>An abomination, to be precise.</sub>

---

What should the class do? Easy:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}
    {}% do nothing, equation* is already available
    {\newenvironment{equation*}{\displaymath}{\enddisplaymath}}%
}
```